# Application crashing due to high memory usage

Tags: android, memory, crash

I am creating an activity in which there is an api hit.
But when i am opening that activity 3-4 times ,it starts crashing and shows this :

```
Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 46562(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 13MB/15MB, paused 7.087ms total 41.571ms


Skipped 241 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.


Skipped 356 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread,
```

In android profiler I found out that it does not free memory on finishing the activity and use more memory on open the activity again which lead to high memory usage and ultimately leads to crash.

I have tried everything searched google,stackover flow,android hive but nothing worked.

Comment: You should not call the api on main thread.

Comment: i am using volley ,so this is handled internally

Answer (score 0):

I think you should always make asynchronous call in a background thread, example call API. Handle too much task on main thread cause your performance hiccups due to garbage collection `GC freed 46562`. Make sure you don't keep context or anything can cause leak memory when you hit API. Maybe I can help you better if you show your code.

Comment: i am using volley ,so this is handled internally  and i forget to tell one thing , there is message in last some like - suspending all thread took 58.11 ms